# From Fermions to CAR

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, anticommutator

I do not understand why Fermions statistic is equivalent to the CAR. In other words, suppose we have $\{a_i\}_i$ set of Fermionic operators acting on an Hilbert space, they satisfy the Canonical Anticommutation Relations if
$$ \{a_j,a_i^\dagger\} = \delta_{ij},\qquad \{a_i,a_j\}=0$$
where $\{.,.\}$ represents the anticommutator between the two operators. Why the CAR should represent Fermions?

Comment: Well, for example because from $\{a_i,a_j\} = 0$ it follows that $a_i^2 = 0$, which basically reflects Pauli's exclusion principle. So if you define fermions as particles for which this principle holds, then it seems like a good idea to impose the CAR, no?

Comment: Can we say that Fermions are completely characterized by Pauli exclusion principle? How about the indistinguishability? How is it reflected in the CAR? Of course I am missing something, since I cannot fully see that CAR are equivalent to Fermions

Comment: I wish to say that CAR do give indistinguishability. For example in the state  $a_1^{\dagger}a_2^{\dagger} \left | 0 \right>$, it only says there is a particle in state 1 and a particle in state 2, but no information at all about which particle is in which. To be more concrete, 1 can mean a localized state in position $x_1$, and 2 a localized state in position $x_2$. In this case the state means one particle in position $x_1$ and one particle in position $x_2$, but there is no notion of "which particle is at which position" at all. This _is_ indistinguishability.

Comment: It is quite convincing, but why Fermionic states are written in antisymmetric form if states like $a_1^\dagger a_2^\dagger |0\rangle $ are already indistinguishable? Forgive me if I am pedantic, but need to convince myself of the coherence of these aspects of Fermionic theory